# Why won't my computer install version 1.13.1 of tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, jupyter-notebook

I've been struggling with this issue for 3 hours now, I've tried multiple anaconda environments, but it just wont work. I'm trying to use tenforflow version 1.13.1 and I cant get it to pip install

This is the code i've been using (in jupyter notebook)

```
!pip uninstall tensorflow -y
print('-----')
!pip install tensorflow==1.13.1
print('_____')
!pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.13.1
```

and the error i keep receiving is the following:

```
WARNING: Skipping tensorflow as it is not installed.
-------
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.13.1 (from versions: 2.2.0rc3, 2.2.0rc4, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.3.0rc0, 2.3.0rc1, 2.3.0rc2, 2.3.0, 2.3.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.13.1
_______
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu==1.13.1 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu==1.13.1
```

Can anybody save me from this path of total error???

Comment: What is the python version you are using?

Comment: You are probably using Python 3.8 for which only those versions are available as pip wheels.

Comment: @ORLEVII 3.6.12

Comment: Are you sure about that? I see that you are running your commands from a jupyter notebook. Can you please run `!python -V` ?

Comment: Create a new env with Python=3.5.6. it worked for me tensoflow==1.13.2

Answer (score 7):

TensorFlow dropped the support of versions `1.*` in python 3.8: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39768

I would try working with python 3.7 or 3.6 instead

Comment: I'm working in python 3.6.12, so that shouldnt be the issue

Comment: @Britta  which version  did compatible for tensorflow 1. *